# How can I share my slack app between my workspaces?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I've just created an app (slash command) and install it in one of my workspaces. But now I want to add the same app to another one. Is it possible without distribution to App Directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to add you Slack app to another workspace, you can do so without going through the process of placing it on the App directory.

All you need to do is

1. add the ability to install your app to an workspace using OAuth 2.0.
2. enable public distribution

So instead of clicking "Install app to this workspace", which works great for private Slack app, which live in one workspace only, you need a script than can be called from a web browser to run the [Oauth installation routine](https://api.slack.com/docs/oauth). This is usually done by adding a [Slack button](https://api.slack.com/docs/slack-button) to your website.

You also need to enable "public distribution" for your app. Note, that is not the same as putting them on the App Directory, which requires submitting your app and undergoing a review by the Slack team.

Answer (score -2):

Found the answer, in the small grey caption in the app creation form

> Your app belongs to this workspace—leaving this workspace will remove your ability to manage this app. Unfortunately, this can’t be changed later.

Comment: This is incorrect, you can add a Slack app to other workspaces without distribution to App directory

Comment: Can you share the solution?

Comment: @ErikKalkoken how?