# Issue in communicating with Slack Channel on second Slack work space in MS Bot framework

Tags: botframework, slack

Posting an issue here to see if anyone has experienced this.

**My Setup:**
MS Bot Service setup with Bot Channel Registration done for Slack, and the bot hosted on a different cloud (currently on my local machine).

I was able to successfully link the channel using the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0).

**Problem:** 
Though I was able to successfully communicate with the bot using the Slack channel that was configured on my workspace, I couldn't share the link of the app to a different user's workspace.

I got the link to share the slack app from the 'Get Bot Embed Codes' link in the Channel registration page.

```
<a href="https://slack.com/oauth/authorize?scope=bot&client_id=xxxxxxx.xxxxxxx&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fslack.botframework.com%2fHome%2fauth&state=xxxxxxx"><img height="40" width="139" src="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png" srcset="https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack.png 1x, https://platform.slack-edge.com/img/add_to_slack@2x.png 2x"></a>
```

It seems that after the user clicks the link, the only information I get at the bot is "installationUpdate" type of message. No other messages get passed to the bot from Bot Framework. Is there any other configuration that needs to be done to make this work?

```
 Type: "installationUpdate",
 ID: "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
 Timestamp: "2018-12-26T14:07:53.2146744Z",
 ServiceURL: "https://slack.botframework.com/",
 ChannelID: "slack",
 Text: "",
 Conversation: {
  ID: "BBBBBBBB:TTTTTTT:",
  IsGroup: false
 },
 From: {
  ID: "BBBBBBB:TTTTTTT",
  Name: "botuser"
 },
 Recipient:{
  ID:  "BBBBBBBB:TTTTTTT",
  Name: "botuser"
 }
}
```

Slack supports sharing of Slack App with other users in different workspaces using their 'Add To Slack' button, which I presume is the same as the one I got from the Channel Registration page, except it is changed to suit MS Bot Framework.

So, I am not sure why this is not working.. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Has your app been distributed to the Slack directory?

Comment: No. It is not published to Slack App Directory, but it is enabled for distribution/sharing with other teams. Have you done anything similar and seen it work?

Comment: Ok. Yeah, i've seemingly been able to hit the same behavior (with being distributed/shared to another workspace). I can see the bot, just can't get it to reply. Even when @mentioning it. I don't think this is a bot framework issue, but i'll poke around some.

Comment: Should be possible: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972465/how-can-i-share-my-slack-app-between-my-workspaces

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue on my end. Please verify on your end and then let me know if that solves it for you (and flag this as the answer).

In the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-slack?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) , I had *mistakenly* added the event types to **Subscribe to Workspace Events** and not **Subscribe to Bot Events**. Once added (I did not need to remove from workspace events), I saved changes and then had to re-authorize the app. Once done, that would allow the bot to respond in the additional workspace.

The documentation is correct. I (and I'm guessing you as well) just didn't follow it closely enough. To further clarify; allowing these events must be done after creating the botuser, which is listed lower in the left navigation. The documentation shows the correct steps, it's just not the expected (appropriate?) flow in the Slack API configuration.