# Is it possible to install app to your other workspace that isn't appproval by Slack?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I start explore Slack Api documentation. I just want to create app that will be send notification to my differrent workspaces and channels. Is it possible to create custom app and distribute it between your own workspaces without approval by Slack team?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share my slack app between my workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972465/how-can-i-share-my-slack-app-between-my-workspaces)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You will need to go through the 'Manage Distribution' process, but you do not need to submit your app for Slack's approval before sharing among your own workspaces.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You are correct, however this question has already been answered and marked as duplicate.