# Consume Slack user's data

Tags: slack, slack-api

In my app, I want to consume user's slack data(channel messages, files, user profiles, etc..) like we do it for other services like outlook mail, onedrive, etc.. using OAUTH. User comes to my application and connects his slack account using OAUTH, I want to access his information and do some processing on his data.

To do this, I created an app in slack for my workspace and try to extend it to any other workspace. It seems the oauth login url can not be used for other workspace. To use for other workspaces, it seems I have to publish it to slack's app directory. I submitted my app to slack review. They rejected my app by saying the following conditions.

> Hi there, Thanks for your submission. Given the nature of your service
>   and its primary purpose of ingesting Slack content from a workspace
>   without providing any additional functionality to Slack itself, we
>   have come to the conclusion that the app isn’t a good fit for the App
>   Directory.  It doesn’t go unnoticed that a lot of work was put into
>   the app, so we want to emphasize that this decision doesn’t mean that
>   users can’t continue to use the app or that you can’t market it or
>   distribute it in any way — rather that it simply won’t have a listing
>   in our directory. If you have any follow-up questions please let us
>   know, sorry for the bad news.

My app really don't do anything posting to slack, I am just reading the user's slack data and do processing and showing that information in my app. 
To do this, What should I do? Am I missing something?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I share my slack app between my workspaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48972465/how-can-i-share-my-slack-app-between-my-workspaces)